# Typescript flatten array with RXJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs, flatten

I'm banging my head with an issue I'm having with a RXJS transformation in a Ionic 2 application.
I'd like to flat a json file into object, this is my semplified json file

```
    [{
     "lingua": "it",
     "labels": {
        "denominazione": "Hi",
     },
     "tipologie": [
      {"denominazione": "test 1"},
      {"denominazione": "test 2"}
    ]
    },...]
```

this is the snippet of typescript code

```
    export class MyRecord{
       denominazione: string;
       label_denominazione: string;

       constructor(denominazione: string, label_denominazione: string) {
          this.denominazione = denominazione;
          this.label_denominazione = label_denominazione;
       }
    }

    public getRecords() {
       var url = '../assets/records.json'; 
       let records$ = this.http
          .get(url)
          .map(mapRecords);
    return records$;

    function mapRecords(response: Response): MyRecord[] {
       return response.json().filter(x => x.lingua == "it")
        .map(({ lingua, labels, tipologie }) => tipologie.map(tipologia =>
        toMyRecord(labels, tipologia))
       );
    }

    function toMyRecord(l: any, t: any): MyRecord{
      let record= new MyRecord(
        t.denominazione,
        l.denominazione,
      );
      return record;
    }
```

When I call the service:

```
    members: MyRecord[];
    this.myService.getRecords().subscribe(res => {
        this.members = res;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
```

What I get in **this.members** is an array of array of **MyRecord**:

```
    [[{ label_denominazione: "Hi", denominazione: "test 1"}, { label_denominazione: "Hi", denominazione: "test 2"} ]]
```

instead of an array of MyRecord:

```
    [{ label_denominazione: "Hi", denominazione: "test 1"}, { label_denominazione: "Hi", denominazione: "test 2"} ]
```

I've tried to use flatMap (mergeMap), but I've got the error 'flatMap is not a function' (btw I've imported the operator mergeMap).
I'm also wondering as **this.members** defined as **MyRecord** array can accept a different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here seems to be a problem:

```
function mapRecords(response: Response): MyRecord[] {
   return response.json().filter(x => x.lingua == "it")
    .map(({ lingua, labels, tipologie }) => tipologie.map(tipologia =>
    toMyRecord(labels, tipologia))
   );
}
```

instead of 1st `map` try `reduce` like this, which merges mappings:

```
function mapRecords(response: Response): MyRecord[] {
   return response.json().filter(x => x.lingua == "it")
      .reduce((result, current, idx) => 
          result.concat(current.topologie.map(tipologia =>
              toMyRecord(current.labels, tipologia)));
      }, []);
}
```

and it should do the thing.

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm, as @alebianco has pointed out I thought to still operate with an Observable.

Comment: oh I thought that you gave up on `flatMap`. So to stay on Observable we would have to fix your setup first. For me it works `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';`. Paste in your attempts with `flatMap` so that we can have a look

Comment: On second thought, why do you want stick to Observable? For me it looks like one shot request. I would do sth like `get().toPromise().then(/*handleResponse*/).catch(/*handleBigNoNo*/)`

Comment: That's ok, your solution works fine, as I said I got error when I replaced the first **map** with **flatMap** even if I've added the operator. I don't want to stick on Observable, I just didn't know that 'response.json()' returns a plain object. Thanks again for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` returns a plain object, not an observable. From that point forward you're operating on a simple Array with the standard Array methods, which do not include `flatMap`.

You could convert that into an observable with `Observable.from` but I don't see the point in doing that based on the operation you're doing in the example. Just use a different strategy to map/reduce that Array.